# Angular2 FileSaver Octet/Stream How to Show Download Status on Browser File Downloader?

Tags: angular, http, progress

I have tried a lot of things for this but I still can't get it to work. I'm using Angular2 and `file-saver`. I call an API that I wrote that will send a file in an octet-stream format. When inspecting I see the file is downloading, and when I wait for the whole file to download it then shows up in my Chrome browser in the bottom left corner. However, I would like to see the bytes/mb being downloaded in my browser so the user knows something is happening. This is what happens when you download big files from say AWS in the browser. When I just hit my API without Angular2, just put it in my browser, I get exactly what I want - a file shows up and chrome and I can see the bytes being downloaded. Does anybody have any suggestions? I have also seen I could use reportProgress in the http header but I do not want to display the progress in the code/UI, I just want it to show up in the browser. Thanks for any help!

Also to note - I am downloading a file from S3, but due to security restrictions I can't get a presigned URL or anything like that, so I have to use my API as a proxy.

Code:

```
import {saveAs} from 'file-saver';

            const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/s3downloader/serveS3File/';
            const s3Path = encodeURIComponent(this.processedFilesSelected[0]);
            const headers = new HttpHeaders({
                Authorization: 'Bearer ', // Auth header
                // Accept: 'application/json',
                // ContentDisposition: 'attachment',
                // Connection: 'keep-alive',
                // ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
                // responseType: 'blob'
            });
            return this.http2.get(url + s3Path, {headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' }).toPromise().then(
                blob => {
                    saveAs(blob, this.processedFilesSelected[0].substring(this.processedFilesSelected[0].lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
                    // const url2 = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    // window.open(url2);
                }
            );
```

The commented out headers are also what I am sending in the response header of my API.